# /usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lvtkGUISupportQt

Tags: ubuntu, ros, 3d-mapping

I'm trying to build a [package](https://github.com/introlab/rtabmap_ros) i've found on github,when I run the command make, it gives me the error in the Title.

I'm working on Ubuntu 16.04, it seems that tere's a library missing but don't know how to fix the problem on Ubuntu.

Here's the complete message I'm getting:

```
hamza@hamza-Latitude-5590:~/rtabmap/build$ make 
[  4%] Built hamza@hamza-Latitude-5590:~/rtabmap/build$ make 
[  4%] Built target rtabmap_utilite
[  4%] Built target res_tool
[  4%] Linking CXX shared library ../../../bin/librtabmap_core.so
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lvtkGUISupportQt
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
corelib/src/CMakeFiles/rtabmap_core.dir/build.make:3041: recipe for target '../bin/librtabmap_core.so.0.19.2' failed
make[2]: *** [../bin/librtabmap_core.so.0.19.2] Error 1
CMakeFiles/Makefile2:267: recipe for target 'corelib/src/CMakeFiles/rtabmap_core.dir/all' failed
make[1]: *** [corelib/src/CMakeFiles/rtabmap_core.dir/all] Error 2
Makefile:149: recipe for target 'all' failed
make: *** [all] Error 2
target rtabmap_utilite
[  4%] Built target res_tool
[  4%] Linking CXX shared library ../../../bin/librtabmap_core.so
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lvtkGUISupportQt
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
corelib/src/CMakeFiles/rtabmap_core.dir/build.make:3041: recipe for target '../bin/librtabmap_core.so.0.19.2' failed
make[2]: *** [../bin/librtabmap_core.so.0.19.2] Error 1
CMakeFiles/Makefile2:267: recipe for target 'corelib/src/CMakeFiles/rtabmap_core.dir/all' failed
make[1]: *** [corelib/src/CMakeFiles/rtabmap_core.dir/all] Error 2
Makefile:149: recipe for target 'all' failed
make: *** [all] Error 2
```

Answer (score 0):

What you are experiencing is the pcl version with QT plugin version issue.  the older version and new version are not compatible. I encounter this b4.

(1)Its either you build with the correct version pcl that all other package is ok with.

(2) or just user docker to install this rtabmap.  In this way, all condition will be fufilled.

follow the link here for detail walk through https://github.com/introlab/rtabmap/wiki/Installation#docker